# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile' or Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, jwt

I m working for MEANAUTH application and i want to access user profile using angular jwt ,when i try to login and access users profile `https://localhost:3000/prifile`i am getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`or when i try to use these url `http://localhost://localhost:3000/users/profile``, i am getting this error  Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'users/profile'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'users/profile'

here is my code

## auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

   authToken: any;
   user: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    registerUser(user){
     let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user , {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res);
    }

    authenticateUser(user):Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user , {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res);

    }

    getProfile():Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      this.loadToken();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res);

    }

    storeUserDate(token, user){
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.authToken = token;
      this.user = user;
    }

    loadToken(){
      const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      this.authToken = token;
    }

    logout(){
      this.authToken = null;
      this.user = null;
      localStorage.clear();
    }

  }
```

## profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Object;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
     err => {
       console.log(err);
       return false;
     });

  }

}
```

## profile.html

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <h2 class="page-header">{{user.name}}</h2>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Username : {{user.username}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Email : {{user.email}}</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

and here is my passport restApi code, my rest application is working fine but when i try to integrate with angular client it will show err.

## users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/database");
const User = require("../models/user");

//Register
 router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  //res.send('REGISTER');
  let newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ success: false, msg: "Failed to register user" });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: true, msg: "User registered" });
    }
  });
});


//Authenticate
 router.post("/authenticate", (req, res, next) => {
  //res.send('AUTHENTICATE');
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ success: false, msg: "User not found!" });
    }
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
        const token = jwt.sign({
          type: "user",
          data:{
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
         },config.secret,{
           expiresIn: 604800
         }
        );
        return res.json({
           success: true,
           token: "JWT "+ token,
            user:{
            id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
        }else{
          return res.json({
             success: true,
             msg: "Worng Password."
          });
        }
    });
  });
});



//Profile
router.get("/profile", passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
 // res.send("PROFILE");
 res.json({user: req.user});
}); 

/* router.get("/profile", passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req,res) =>{
  console.log(req.user);
 return res.json(
   req.user
 );
})
  */

module.exports = router;
```

## passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    })
     );
  }
```

any help highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Because when you login or register you get jwt token in response, store that jwt token into localstorage and when you make api call of user profile at that time get that jwt token from localstorage and append with your headers.i hope it will work for you.

Comment: please go through my code and tell where is problem@vivek bharda